# How can I preview live(on browser) with the hbs format

Tags: intellij-idea, browser

I use the editor intellij Idea how can I debug an hbs file in the browser, the problem is that the file is displayed but it only shows the code on the page, it does not display the content itself

Comment: I'm no webdev, but don't you need to compile/convert your hbs file to html before opening it in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars can't be directly executed by the browser, you have to compile them first, like

```
<!-- Include Handlebars from a CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
<script>
  // compile the template
  var template = Handlebars.compile("Handlebars <b>{{doesWhat}}</b>");
  // execute the compiled template and print the output to the console
  console.log(template({ doesWhat: "rocks!" }));
</script>
```

See https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/#installation

Comment: I have a question, the html syntaxes can be used within the hbs file, because to see the entire form I did it using html, that could not be the problem for which it is not displayed in the browser?

Comment: HTML code can be used in hbs template, but still the template can't be run directly. If your `.hbs` file doesn't include any template code, i.e. if it's a pure HTML, try renaming it to `.html` to preview it in browser